# Lifting heavier weights with my right arm

Tags: weightlifting, muscle, muscle-imbalance, toning

I have differently shaped shoulders through a disability so I purposely work my right arm with heavier dumbells.  What is the consequence of doing this to the left side of my body?  I mean is there corresponding muscles that could inadvertently be toning my left side whilst working my right?
I think my lower back on my left has more definition. Could that be due to more strength training on my right arm?  Thank you

Comment: Is your disability still with you? By that I mean, do you expect to have near-normal use at some point?

Answer (score 1):

Everyone has a more dominant side than another, and after a few years of good living most people have picked up random injuries. My [left hip adductor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adductor_muscles_of_the_hip), as an example, has some damage in it so I can never really do as much on my left side as my right. Worse, I'm right handed so I end up using my right side more for pretty much everything.

Muscle imbalances can be a problem, and although the "go see a doctor" can be applied too widely you should have a firm understanding of what kind of use and mobility you can expect from your left side. A good physical therapist will be able to give you very targeted exercises that will strengthen surrounding musculature without causing any new problems.

There are some amputee athletes out there that are in phenomenal shape, and that's been primarily through physical therapy setting the direction and the disabled person themselves doing a boat load of work.

In short, muscle imbalances are common and universal. But when they border on or cross over into disability management, you need a plan that really works for you set up by someone who understands your situation.